# How to count integer values stored in a variable using php?

Tags: php

I am developing a web form which have a field 'marks' where user can put marks... I want to force the user to  input only marks less then 4 digits. Here is function for this purpose but it is not working...

```
Function validate($marks) 
If(strlen($marks)<=4 && !filter_var($marks, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
```

)

```
Return false;
```

Else

```
Return true ;
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself? Please show some code.

Comment: Thanks for such informational answers. Actually i am learning php that's why i want to implement using only php.i have edited my question again to show my code which i am trying

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using only HTML5 input options (PHP is unnecessary for this application).

If your input is `type="number"` you can use `min=-9999 max=9999` to limit the number to 4 digits.

If your input is `type="text"` you can use `maxlength=4` to limit to 4 characters.

Here is a list of input types and options that might help: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the `maxlength` attribute of the `input` tag.

e.g.

```
<input type='text' maxlength='4' name='marks' />
```

Depending on how you want to implement this, you can use javascript too, which will allow you to display some dynamic warning info when it is less than 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with php you can do it like this if the data type is an integer or a float:

```
if ($marks <= 9999.99) {
    //do something
}
```

If it is a string representation of numbers, you can do it like this:

```
if (strlen($marks) <= 4) {
    // do something
}
```